# Ubuntu 17.10 freezing after login

Tags: 17.10, freeze

I've just upgraded my system from 16.04 to 17.10, it was working just fine until I forced it to shut down once(It won't shutdown itself). I've updated some softwares before shutting it down, like shadowsocks and tweaks, I think that has nothing to do with the issue but who knows. Now the machine will freeze whenever I enter my password, the screen goes black and nothing else happens, I really need some help here.